# Displaying alt tag on website

Tags: xpages

We are using carousel code and need to get alt="blah blah" tags for the images.  Does anyone know haow to accomplish this?
Our code:

```
<xe:carousel>
    <xe:this.slideNodes>
        <xe:slide loaded="${viewScope.images[0].url ne null}" buttonStyleClass="btn btn-link">
            <xe:this.backgroundSrc>
                <![CDATA[${javascript:viewScope.images[0].url}]]>
            </xe:this.backgroundSrc>
            <xe:this.buttonLabel>
                <![CDATA[${javascript:viewScope.ctitles[0]}]]>
            </xe:this.buttonLabel>
            <xe:this.descriptionText>
                <![CDATA[${javascript:viewScope.captions[0]}]]>
            </xe:this.descriptionText>
            <xe:this.buttonHref>
                <![CDATA[${javascript:viewScope.pageurl[0]}]]>
            </xe:this.buttonHref>
            <xe:this.buttonStyle>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:viewScope.newwindow[0]}]]>
            </xe:this.buttonStyle>
        </xe:slide>
    </xe:this.slideNodes>
</xe:carousel>
```

Can't find answer out there.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if it's not available via the default properties I would set it via csjs when the document is ready.